# Delete Ad-group permissions powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to delete all permissions to all AD-Security groups.
I need some help in two steps:

1- Obtain all security groups (now I obtain only the name's like newgro.

2- removing permissions for that group. I can't use ParentWeb.RoleAssigments... because I have a AD group, not a Sharepoint group. I try to cast but it doesn't works.

Here my code:

```
            #Get all security groups an remove permissions (inaccesible)

            $groups = Get-ADGroup -filter 'Name -like"newgro*"' | Select-Object Name

            foreach($group in $groups)
            {
                Try
                {
                    $spGroup = $SPWeb.SiteGroups[$group]
                    $ra = $spGroup.ParentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal($spGroup)
                    $ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll()
                    $ra.Update()
                }
                Catch
                {
                    Write-Host "All Roles has been removed"
                }                 
            $log = $root.Url + ',' + $SPWeb.Url + ',' + $group.Name +  ',Unlock,None'
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the first question, changing the filter will get you all security groups:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"'
```

sorry, I don't have a SharePoint box to test the 2nd part of the question.

Comment: thanks @FrozenSoul It  works for me. but now, I have the second problem. to remove all permissions for the security group. Do you have a little example, don't worry if it doesn't works.

Comment: You can probably look at this script:"Add a SharePoint or AD group/user to all sites in a site collection using PowerShell "
this link:http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/add-sharepoint-or-ad-groupuser-to-all.html

its the opposite of what you are trying to do, but should be a valid framework , just needing to change add to remove and edit to fit your needs.

I haven't run a SP server in many years and don't have any PS/SharePoint code of my own.  I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.